# HmacSha256 signature generated is different in Java than in Go

Tags: java, go, hmac

I'm converting code from Go to Java. The source to convert is at https://github.com/h2non/imaginary#url-signature and this is my current code converted to Java.

The problem is that I'm missing something, since the signature generated in Java is different than the one in Go.

Expected result (as in source in Go):

> ruEWRoFO-ic-L38vTsjqIYE6DLZ532CTaZXOh1gwuVo

Actual result in Java:

> x2clz4ynSxcFPNc6h3W832vyrIQ=

My code in Java:

```
@Test
public void testSomeString() throws Exception {
    String signKey = "4f46feebafc4b5e988f131c4ff8b5997";
    String urlPath = "/resize";
    String urlQuery = "file=image.jpg&height=200&type=jpeg&width=300";

    byte[] signKeyAsBytes = signKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
    SecretKey SHA256_KEY = new SecretKeySpec(signKeyAsBytes, "HmacSHA256");

    byte[] hashAsBytes=Hashing.hmacSha1(SHA256_KEY)
            .newHasher()
            .putString(urlPath, UTF_8)
            .putString(urlQuery, UTF_8)
            .hash().asBytes();
    String hash = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(hashAsBytes);

    //correct value in GoLang is: "ruEWRoFO-ic-L38vTsjqIYE6DLZ532CTaZXOh1gwuVo"
    Assert.assertEquals("ruEWRoFO-ic-L38vTsjqIYE6DLZ532CTaZXOh1gwuVo", hash);

    /*
    Junit test fails with:
    Expected :ruEWRoFO-ic-L38vTsjqIYE6DLZ532CTaZXOh1gwuVo
    Actual   :x2clz4ynSxcFPNc6h3W832vyrIQ=
    */
}
```

And this is the original in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    signKey := "4f46feebafc4b5e988f131c4ff8b5997"
    urlPath := "/resize"
    urlQuery := "file=image.jpg&height=200&type=jpeg&width=300"

    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(signKey))
    h.Write([]byte(urlPath))
    h.Write([]byte(urlQuery))
    buf := h.Sum(nil)

    fmt.Println("sign=" + base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(buf))
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to parse `signKey` as hex? Now you're converting the individual characters to bytes which doesn't sound like something you want to do.

Comment: As I understand Go it is converted straight from String to byte[] without base64. see ` []byte(signKey)`  .I understand that signKey looks like Hex, but I believe this is not Hex.

Comment: Why would you believe that's not hexadecimal? I can't imagine any programmer looking at the value and not thinking "that's binary data encoded in hexadecimal". I'm not familiar with Go, but you could have the same bug in both codes.

Comment: Any chance that the error is due to calling `hmacSha1` in Java? I mean, look at how much shorter the generated string is - it looks like it's probably half the length of the go one. You're probably not doing sha256.

Comment: What is the `UTF_8` value you're passing to `putString()` in Java?

Comment: public static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

Comment: @icza: the strings here contain only ASCII chars and their encoding on any JavaSE platform is not affected by the charset -- although _other_ strings could be.

Comment: @Kayaman `signKey` is a string, it's not a base16 number. I'm not sure what your (in)familiarity with Go has to do with that. In Go strings are (basically) immutable  byte slices, so type-casting a string to a byte slice works quite well.

Comment: @Dynom I know the **type** is String, but the contents are hexadecimal. That usually means the String will be *parsed* into bytes, not converted into bytes. Especially if you're working with cryptographic keys. Now each byte can have 16 values instead of the normal 256. That's not something you want to see in cryptographic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `Hashing` class you are using in Java, because it isn't standard, but if I use the standard class `javax.crypto.Mac` to do HmacSHA256 (NOT HmacSHA1) with that key and data -- and encode with the 'unpadded URLsafe' variant of Base64 promoted by JSON, not the traditional one Java defaults to -- I do get `ruEWRoFO-ic-L38vTsjqIYE6DLZ532CTaZXOh1gwuVo`.

However, it is very poor practice to sign the path and query without some delimiting -- this may allow a signature to be 'moved' to different data. It is also weird, though not directly dangerous, to use a key that is characters but only hex digit characters. I wouldn't use a scheme designed like this for anything important without extensive investigation.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is the final WORKING solution

```
package hashingImaginary;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class apacheHashingTest {

@Test
public void testWithJavaHmacApacheBase64() throws Exception {
    String urlPath = "/resize";
    String urlQuery = "file=image.jpg&height=200&type=jpeg&width=300";

    String signKey = "4f46feebafc4b5e988f131c4ff8b5997";
    String message = urlPath + urlQuery;

    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(signKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

    String hash = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
    System.out.println(hash);

    Assert.assertEquals("ruEWRoFO-ic-L38vTsjqIYE6DLZ532CTaZXOh1gwuVo", hash);
}
}
```

Comment: Note that the *effective* size of `signKey` is 128 bits since each character is limited to 4 bits (`0-f`). This is what we call a security flaw.